# Algorithm for finding relations in an algebra

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

I have a sub-algebra of the algebra of polynomials in $n$ variables, given by a set of $k \le n$ generators. Is there an algorithm to find all the possible relations these generators satisfy?

In other words my subalgebra will be isomorphic to $k[x_1,\dots,x_k]/I$ and I want an algorithm to find generators for $I$.

Comment: Is there a specific reason I've been downvoted? Can someone explain how I can improve my question? :)

Comment: I would assume that the downvote is a knee-jerk reaction from someone who sees a problem statement and no attempts or thoughts on your part. It's common enough here, but I still think it's bad form to do it without also leaving an explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [Buchberger's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buchberger%27s_algorithm) for finding a [Gröbner basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6bner_basis).